# LSTM models and Cross Validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, lstm

I have constructed a simplistic LSTM model using the keras package. The model takes sales data over a time series and tries to forecast future sales. The model I currently have groups the number of sales by product and by store. For simplicity I keep the number of products to 1 and number of stores to be 6. I then run a rolling origin function across a time series of 12 periods.

The rolling origin function is not important but it means that there are `1 (product) * 5 (stores) * 6 (periods) - or (1*5*6 = 30 LSTM models)`. Currently the model trains and tests on 30 models.

I set the number of epochs to 300 and add 6 layers with varying level of units. The number of epochs, layers and units are arbitrary at this stage.

The model (in R and using the pipe function `(%>%)`) looks something like the following:

```
model %>%
    layer_lstm(units            = 100, 
               input_shape      = c(1, 1), 
               batch_size       = 40,
               return_sequences = TRUE, 
               stateful         = TRUE) %>% 
    layer_lstm(units            = 100, 
               return_sequences = FALSE, 
               stateful         = TRUE) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 1)
```

Where I just add another layer `layer_lstm` to the model in order to increase the number of layers.

The original model I described above took 18 hours to run on a CPU (I understand I would need access to GPUs or Amazon Web services).

What I would like to know is how I should run cross validation on the models. It is computationally infeasible to run the model on `30 (products) * 5 (stores) * 6 (periods) * 50 (states in the US)`

Should I train each product for all 50 U.S. states and then use the best parameters and test it at the store level? - this way I will lost a lot of state level characteristics - i.e. Idaho might like a certain brand more than New Jersey but the model is trained on a macro level and will miss these characteristics.

I am looking to find the optimal number of epochs, layers and units to apply to each layer - but this will vary heavily depending on which produt I will use and which state I am in, and I simply do not have the computing resources to test on all products, states and stores...

---

This is a research project idea so any additions, suggestions, modifications are always appreciated.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you need one model per period? Why don't you do multistep forecasting using the same model that way you have only 5 models instead of 30? Additionally,  you are correct in a assuming that a model trained on national level aggregate data won't perform well for individual stores. However you could group the stores into similar regions (by climate, urban/suburban/rural, etc...) and then use that model to approximate individual stores.

Comment: Perhaps you are right to train the model once and then apply it at multi step forecasting as consumer spending on certain products are seasonal (i.e. more sales for holidays etc.) but also ther are some non-seasonal products (toothpaste etc.) - I was following this blog where they used a `rolling_origin` function - I thought perhaps consumer spending might change over the years slightly... But perhaps I should perform cross validation for just one period and use these parameters for all periods. Perhaps I should group the stores somehow also.

Comment: As a general comment how is CV performed on LSTM models, I have applied CV using a grid search for an XGBoost model but not for neural networks which require more computational power.